# Flutter Doctor - Android toolchain (Missing)

Tags: flutter

I ran a fresh installation of the latest version of Flutter and then ran `flutter doctor`. Everything is fine but I always get this error (this is why I am reinstalling flutter):-

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.   
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
```

I have tried several fix like going to this website -> https://www.programsbuzz.com/article/set-android-environment-variable-path-windows-10 but nothing works. PLease help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can either run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and it will install  the command line tools or if it is giving an error regarding the path of **sdkmanager** then you can install Android Studio and install command line tools directly from there.

Go to **SDK Manager** > **Android SDK** > Check on **Android SDK Command-Line Tools**

Then click on apply and it will install all the required dependencies.

Run `flutter doctor` to check if everything is installed successfully or not.

[image: Android SDK Command-Line Tools]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Terminal and Simply Run :

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

It will solve this issue .

Comment: THe above command is not helpful for me. I have ran the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Mac specific issue, everything was installed correctly, all the SDKs were there, all the tools were downloaded.

The problem was that the $PATH did not like having a `~` in it. From the Google docs:

```
export ANDROID_HOME ~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH $PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

What works on my machine is:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
```

(And then `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and restart android studio)